# "AudioKit v5-main" crashes with mic Pitch Tap

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I use "AudioKit v5-main" to implement the recording function.
The recording function is working properly, but it crashes when I try to tap the input from the microphone.

The code is:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let engine = AudioEngine()
    var silence: Fader!
    var boostMic: Fader!
    var tracker: PitchTap!
    var recorder: NodeRecorder!
    var player = AudioPlayer()
    var mixer = Mixer()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        guard let mic = engine.input else {
            debugPrint("error")
            return
        }
        boostMic = Fader(mic, gain: 5)
        
        tracker = PitchTap(boostMic, handler: { (pitch, amp) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                debugPrint("amp: \(amp.first!.description)")
            }
        })
        
        do {
            recorder = try NodeRecorder(node: boostMic)
        } catch {
            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        
        silence = Fader(boostMic, gain: 0)
        mixer.addInput(silence)
        mixer.addInput(player)
        engine.output = mixer
        
        Settings.audioInputEnabled = true
        do {
            try engine.start()
            tracker.start()
            NodeRecorder.removeTempFiles()
            try recorder.record()
        } catch {
            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

The errors output during a crash are:

```
[avae]            AVAEInternal.h:76    required condition is false: [AVAEGraphNode.mm:817:CreateRecordingTap: (nullptr == Tap())]
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: nullptr == Tap()'
```

The development environment is as follows:

macOS 10.15.7

xCode 12.2 (12B45b)

AudioKit v5-main branch

Test with actual iPhoneX

Is there a way to avoid the crash?

Comment: Hey, have you found a solution? I am facing the same problem

Answer (score -6):

I solved this problem by modifying the AudioKit framework.

Comment: Explain what you modified so your answer is useful to anyone.